# write application event information with Win32 API

Tags: .net, c++, windows, events

.NET provides EventLog class that be able to write application event information to a particular log on the system. Is there simliar Win32 API that can be called with C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want Event Tracing for Windows:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968803(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's documented in the Event Logging section on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That would be the **Windows Event Logging API** for Vista and later: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780%28VS.85%29.aspx

Or for pre-Vista, you want the just-plain **Event Logging API**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363652%28VS.85%29.aspx